# Using Intent to Update UI

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a networking app that needs to update the data counter in the app's UI as bytes are being sent and received simultaneously. Have tried implementing an intent which carries the code this way:

`intent.putExtra("received", last_rx)
 intent.putExtra("sent", last_tx)`

The issue is I can't call `setResult()` as the method where this intent is placed is not a View meaning I can't get the intents from `onActivityResult`. Is there a workaround or a better way to update my UI.

Please note that I call the last_rx and last_tx from other classes as a double like this::

```
myclass.last_rx += s.length();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should try [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus). It won't break your logic. EventBus a really nice, easy to use "publish/subscribe event bus optimized for Android".

If you really want to use intents for communication you have 2 options:

- start activity with  "singleTask" or "singleInstance" mode. New
  activity wont be created and you get your intent in onNewIntent()
  method. (bad way)
- register local broadcast reciever in your activity. See docs how
  to use it correctly.

Comment: Just started using EventBus now. The library is so good and also most importantly didn't break my logic.Thanks @leonidis